# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` as a subview of a `UIViewController`. The viewController UI is managed through a storyboard. The delegate and datasource are set to the viewController as required.

I have the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (updateType == Profile) {
        return 15;
    }
    else {
        return 6;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

The above two methods are called exactly as they should. Calling `[self.tableview reloadData]` results in the methods being called again. The baffling part is that `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is never called. Ever.

The datasource and delegate are set in code where `self.tableview` is an IBOutlet to the `UITableView` in the storyboard:

```
self.tableview.delegate = self;
self.tableview.dataSource = self;
```

**Answer Found**

I am using storyboards with auto layout. The issue was that the dimensions were set to wRegular hRegular despite the rest of the storyboard been set to wAny hAny. Simply switching this has made it work! Ridiculous I know but it is an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Try to set delegate and datasource in code and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Also, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698313/uitableview-method-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called is really interesting case when this function can not be called. Check it.

Comment: Thanks Oleshko  - the delegate and datasource are already set in code. I tried the suggestion re constraints but that made no difference.

Comment: Hm... Try to delete cellForRowAtIndexPath method at all and seeing if you would have some warning that this method is not implemented.

Comment: I tried that initially to see if there was some hidden exception/issue but it makes no difference whether the cellForRowAtIndexPath is there or not

Comment: did u check my answer

Comment: Have you confirmed that your tableview is actually on screen and that you have set a row height?

Comment: if u solve the problem then i m interested to know ur methods of solving

Answer (score 1):

There are a few situations that delegate methods are not called. Therefore, check your setup first through debugging tool to see whether your setup is appropriate like checking whether existence of table view, delegate and dataSource in memory. If your data source is empty, the table view will not even try to call which is not your case since you do return certain number.

Normally, it's just a small mistakes that programmers made based on what I made and saw before. So, double and triple check your code. And you better post your 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as well.

UPDATE FROM WRITER's ANSWER:
It turns out that the table view is not visible under some size class. That's why **iOS** will not even try because it's not visible at all. This is not a bug from **Apple** and it can be detected by view debugging.

Comment: The delegate and datasource methods are correctly set up - the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection methods are called correctly.

Comment: Man, I was there before and it turned out that it was just stupid mistake. Or can you possibly give me more information so that we can help you effectively.

Comment: Your approach is definitely correct and I have been burnt by this very thing in the past but this not the case here. Everything is set correctly. What other information will help you to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using storyboards with auto layout. The issue was that the dimensions were set to wRegular hRegular despite the rest of the storyboard been set to wAny hAny. Simply switching this has made it work! Ridiculous I know but it is an answer nonetheless!

*This works:*
[image: This works]

*This does not:* 
[image: This doesnt]

This has driven me crazy for far too long and I still do not fully understand the mechanics as to why this works but it does.

Comment: Right now, I see why the delegate method is not called. Because in wRhR size class, your table view's constraints get uninstalled because maybe you do not support this size. So, in this size class the table view will become 0 height. Then, iOS detects that it's not visual. It turns out that iOS does not even want to try to call it because it's invisible. This is definitely not a bug from Apple. It's the size class that literally remove your table view.

Comment: You solve it yourself and we have no way to help you. Anyway, glad to see that it's making sense. Another way to detect is to use view debugging and you will see your table view is a line under that size class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your dataSource and delegate are set to the right classes? It's easy to goof in IB especially if you copy/paste. Put a breakpoint in your viewDidAppear method then in the console call

```
po self.tableView.dataSource
```

to verify that it is set at runtime.

Comment: I set the datasource and delegate in code so this can not be the issue. Also, the other two data source methods are called correctly so the link is definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you set the table view outlet on the interface builder?, i.e. `self.tableView != nil`

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case nothing but numberOfRowsInSection was being called until I flipped the separator on the tableview to single line for some reason (had it set to none), then my heightForRowAtIndexPath was called afterwards where I had some custom sizing calculations being done on a font with the wrong font name, which made it flip out.  Not sure if this helps anyone, but this is what happened to me.