# cellForRowAt not called for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, ios13

I have read [UITableView method cellForRowAtIndexPath not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698313/uitableview-method-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called) and tried every combination of constraints....and I'm convinced my issue is unrelated.

Maybe it has something to do with my TableLoader class? I'm trying to avoid setting the ViewController as UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, that is why I created a second class. Any ideas? Thank you

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loader = TableLoader(tableIn: table)
        loader.loadData()
    }


}

class TableLoader: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    init(tableIn: UITableView ) {
        self.table = tableIn
    }

    func loadData() {
        NSLog("INHE")
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
    }

    let beverages = [
        ("Coke", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Sprite", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Powerade", "2.00", "20 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Blue Moon", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Budweiser", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Bud Light", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Corona", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Dos Equis", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Fat Tire", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Heineken", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Red Stripe", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
        ("Stella Artois", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "Stella Artois Premium Lager"),
        ("Yuengling", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem")]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        NSLog("\(beverages.count)")
        return beverages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        NSLog("hi")
        let cell  = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        //let beverage =
        cell.textLabel?.text = beverages[indexPath.row].0

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching call of `reloadData` to the main queue can fix the problem,

```swift
func loadData() {
  NSLog("INHE")
  table.delegate = self
  table.dataSource = self

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.table.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`class TableLoader: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` the problem seems like here.

You should create a subclass of `UITableView`. This is the straightforward solution.

```
class TableLoader: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

and then a reference for the tableview for the viewController would be

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: TableLoader!
```

and there will be no need to write the extra lines

```
let loader = TableLoader(tableIn: table)
loader.loadData()
```

Also remove the extra outlet in table loader

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
```

because everything has already been initiated